# Geolocation do react native muito lenta

Tags: react-native, geolocalização

Boa tarde.
Qual a forma mais eficiente de pegar a localização do usuário. O método `getCurrentlocation` do geolocation do próprio react-native está demorando em torno de 3 segundo quando habilito o `enableHighAccuracy`, quando está como valor `false` recebo a informação quase imediatamente. Quando testo outra aplicação como o google maps o valor também é rapidamente lido.

Existe outra forma de capturar essa informação?

Comment: Fala rafael, Tudo certo? Se você já tem um código escrito nativamente que faz isso mais rápido, basta expor isso para o JavaScript via NativeModules (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html). Emiliano